# updating a mysql config variable (ft_min_word_len)?

Tags: mysql, linux, configuration

I need to set ft_min_word_len = 3.
I never restarted my mysql server on my production server. So I fear this moment :).

Are there any way to set ft_min_word_len = 3 without restarting mysql?
And if i must restart it, can you tell me the exact step I have to do?

I am on Devian GNU/Linux
MySQL: 5.0.32

(where I can find where is the mysql configuration file?)

Thanks a lot

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html , this variables does not allow changed dynamically. To restart your mysql safely, please move this question to serverfault.com

Comment: i think you'll have to to rebuild all your fulltext indices too :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I'm afraid you need to restart MySQL for it to accept the change. That said, there's nothing to be afraid of, as this won't affect any data. (If you're feeling paranoid, simply carry out the change/restart at an off-peak time, when site traffic is low.)

In terms of the configuration file, I *think* it lives in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` on Debian. (If not, check /etc/my.cnf.)

To restart the service, simply issue a "`/etc/init.d/mysql restart`" command and all should be well.